# How can I make the line be at the end of the text (CSS)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

This is what I want to achieve
[image: get in touch]

This is what I have done but this is not what I want
[image]

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

h3::after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   border-top: 3px solid #000;
   width: 30px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**css**

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h3><span>Get</span> In Touch</h3>
```

Comment: I was thinking too much. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below without extra element and pseudo element:

```css
h3 {
  display:table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) /* color */
    bottom left/ /* position */
    30px 3px  /* width  height */
    no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h3>Get In Touch</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using display:inline-block and position:absolute for your after pseudo element you can do it.

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

h3::after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   border-top: 3px solid #000;
   width: 30px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Get In Touch</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help out @sfili_81. This is resetting the h3 back to it default state (back to the left). I want the h3 to be centered

Comment: Yeah after that you can center it always with css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a span-element to access text elements inside a heading. This way you can add a bottom border to single words:

```css
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <h3><span>Get</span> In Touch</h3>
```